# Знак препинания при описании

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Название темы или видео:

**Зевс()греческий бог**

**Никодим()византийский император.**

Представление кого-то:

**Саша()менеджер.**

Какой знак препинания ставится в таких случаях?
Здесь же можно поставить "или" в значении "то есть",тогда ставится тире?
Так как "то есть" несет в себе и описание,и пояснение(это).
Или ставится запятая?Точка? 
Много где вижу запятую в таких случаях,как и точку.
Объясните, пожалуйста, правила постановки знаков в таких случаях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь, наверное, уместно оформление, как при описании действующих лиц в пьесе, например  в "Грозе" А.Н. Островского:

Савёл Прокофьич Дикой, купец, значительное лицо в городе. Человек злой и скупой.

Марфа Игнатьевна Кабанова (Кабаниха), богатая купчиха, вдова. Властная, жестокая, весьма ограниченная женщина.

Тихон Иванович Кабанов, дворянский сын. Находится в полном подчинении у матери, боится ее. И т.д.

**Примечание.** Чингачгук – Большой Змей, это прозвище (как Ричард Львиное сердце). Это название  фильма,  а имя может писаться без тире.

Answer (score 1):

В названиях чаще используются номинативные предложения, поэтому тире менее уместно. Хотя и встречается:

> > Чингачгук — Большой Змей

Чаще все же запятая:

> > Оцеола, вождь семинолов
> >
> > Ярославна, королева Франции